# Minimisation of Equations and Constraints with Trigonometric Functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have an optimisation script (below), which gives me the error:

> "Undefined function 'cos' for input arguments of type
>   'optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression'."

Just to make sure it wasn't a problem with the `cos` function, I changed the `cos` in `confn2` to a `sin` and then got:

> "Undefined function 'sin' for input arguments of type
>   'optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression'."

However, if I put `cos(pi)` in the Command Window, I do get -1.

I have successfully run this script before with the exception being that the sigma (which appears in the `cos()`) was not an optimisation variable and thus the trig functions were evaluated leaving something linear. Is this type of optimisation script not tractable for constraints with trigonometric functions? Are there alternatives that are within MATLAB?

```
k1 = optimvar('k1', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
k2 = optimvar('k2', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
f = optimvar('f', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
sigma = optimvar('sigma', 'LowerBound', 0, 'UpperBound', 6.28318530718);

obj = fcn2optimexpr(@eq1, k1, k2, f, sigma);

confn1 = obj == 0;
confn2 = -0.9313129901097519*k1 - 1.4693755421886672*k2 - 0.18532000686683578*f*cos((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma)) + 0.9826782255931369*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma)) <= 0;

prob = optimproblem('Objective', obj);

prob.Constraints.confn1 = confn1;
prob.Constraints.confn2 = confn2;

k0.k1 = 0;
k0.k2 = 0;
k0.f = 0;
k0.sigma = 0;

[sol, fval, exitflag, output] = solve(prob, k0)

function f1 = eq1(k1, k2, f, sigma)
f1 = 0.01308996938995749 - 0.3642198710296203*k1 - 0.6784053942919677*k2 + 0.37064001373367156*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
end
```

Comment: `cos` is a recognised function, but not for `"input arguments of type optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression"`. You're essentially doing `cos(sigma)`, which isn't defined because `sigma` isn't a numeric variable, you created it using `optimvar`.

Comment: Hey @Wolfie ! Thanks so much -- that is what I figured as that is when the error occurred. Is there a way to rectify that problem within this optimisation script that allows for `sigma` to remain an `optimvar`, or will I need to write something quite different?

Comment: I have no idea, that's a different question, I've never used `optimproblem`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fmincon`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) instead, in which you can also specify an objective and constraints. This way the `cos` function will be evaluated numerically each iteration, and will not be called with the `optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression` type.

You do need to specify your variables as a vector (intial guess `x0`, lowerbound `lb`, upperbound `ub`), see comment in the code.

```
% x0 = [k1 k2 f sigma];
x0 = [0 0 0 0];
lb = [-3 -3 -3 0];
ub = [3 3 3 2*pi];

% options
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter', 'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-12);

% optimization
x = fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@constrfun, options)

% check constraints to check fulfilment of constraints
[c, ceq] = constrfun(x)
```

Your object function must accept a single vector `x`, which can be 'unpacked' to the individual variables.

```
function f1 = objfun(x)
    k1 = x(1);
    k2 = x(2); 
    f = x(3);
    sigma = x(4);
    f1 = 0.01308996938995749 - 0.3642198710296203*k1 - 0.6784053942919677*k2 + 0.37064001373367156*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
end
```

Your constraints must be defined in a constraint function, that returns `c` and `ceq`, in which `c` is the inequality constraint `c(x) <= 0` and `ceq` is the equality constraint `ceq(x) = 0`.

```
function [c,ceq] = constrfun(x)
    k1 = x(1);
    k2 = x(2); 
    f = x(3);
    sigma = x(4);
    c = -0.9313129901097519*k1 - 1.4693755421886672*k2 - 0.18532000686683578*f*cos((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma)) + 0.9826782255931369*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
    ceq = objfun(x);
end
```

Comment: One thing to note, in this case the `objfun` will be both minimized and has to fulfil the constraint to be zero, which sounds a bit conflicting, but in the end will result in a solution that fulfils the constraint equation minus the tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fcn2optimexpr because of cos(sigma) in the confn2. As of the R2019a release, only ratios of polynomials are allowed for expressions of optimvars.

```
k1 = optimvar('k1', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
k2 = optimvar('k2', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
f = optimvar('f', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
sigma = optimvar('sigma', 'LowerBound', 0, 'UpperBound', 6.28318530718);

obj = fcn2optimexpr(@eq1, k1, k2, f, sigma);
c2 = fcn2optimexpr(@conexpr2, k1, k2, f, sigma);

confn1 = obj == 0;
confn2 = c2 <= 0;

prob = optimproblem('Objective', obj);

prob.Constraints.confn1 = confn1;
prob.Constraints.confn2 = confn2;

k0.k1 = 0;
k0.k2 = 0;
k0.f = 0;
k0.sigma = 0;

options = optimoptions(prob,'Display','iter', 'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-12);
[sol, fval, exitflag, output] = solve(prob, k0, 'Options',options)

objval = evaluate(obj,sol)
c2val = evaluate(c2,sol)


function f1 = eq1(k1, k2, f, sigma)
f1 = 0.01308996938995749 - 0.3642198710296203*k1 - 0.6784053942919677*k2 + 0.37064001373367156*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
end

function c2 = conexpr2(k1, k2, f, sigma)
c2 = -0.9313129901097519*k1 - 1.4693755421886672*k2 - 0.18532000686683578*f*cos((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma)) + 0.9826782255931369*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
end
```

As @rinkert noted, you're using the objective twice. It's not necessary to have an objective function. You can have an optimization problem with just constraints.

```
k1 = optimvar('k1', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
k2 = optimvar('k2', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
f = optimvar('f', 'LowerBound', -3, 'UpperBound', 3);
sigma = optimvar('sigma', 'LowerBound', 0, 'UpperBound', 6.28318530718);

c1 = fcn2optimexpr(@eq1, k1, k2, f, sigma);
c2 = fcn2optimexpr(@conexpr2, k1, k2, f, sigma);

confn1 = c1 == 0;
confn2 = c2 <= 0;

prob = optimproblem();

prob.Constraints.confn1 = confn1;
prob.Constraints.confn2 = confn2;

k0.k1 = 0;
k0.k2 = 0;
k0.f = 0;
k0.sigma = 0;

options = optimoptions(prob,'Display','iter', 'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-12);
[sol, fval, exitflag, output] = solve(prob, k0, 'Options',options)

c1val = evaluate(c1,sol)
c2val = evaluate(c2,sol)


function f1 = eq1(k1, k2, f, sigma)
f1 = 0.01308996938995749 - 0.3642198710296203*k1 - 0.6784053942919677*k2 + 0.37064001373367156*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
end

function c2 = conexpr2(k1, k2, f, sigma)
c2 = -0.9313129901097519*k1 - 1.4693755421886672*k2 - 0.18532000686683578*f*cos((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma)) + 0.9826782255931369*f*sin((1/2)*(-0.372795 + 2*sigma));
end
```